# CiviRules - to trigger a Mosaico templated email (with CiviMosaico extension)?

Tags: civirules, mosaico

Is it possible to trigger sending an email based on a Mosaico template (using the CiviCRM - Mosaico extension?). I'm guessing not, but thought maybe someone had done it, or had a workaround.

Thanks!
..clark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use Mosaico to create message templates](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26568/can-you-use-mosaico-to-create-message-templates)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that it's not possible, because Mosaico doesn't currently support transactional emails, only bulk emails.  I believe Veda is looking for funding from folks willing to sponsor adding Mosaico for transactional emails.

Comment: I have the same understanding @JonG

Comment: For others arriving at this question there is an extension available that has one way synchronization of Mosaico templates for use with scheduled reminders, personal messages, etc. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/28199

Comment: Thank you @mhawksey.  I'm going to nominate this question as a duplicate since that has a clearly better answer than mine.